# is newline treated as space in perl

Tags: perl

consider this perl one liner

```
perl -e "$\=qq{\n};$/=qq{ };while(<>){print;}" "perl.txt" > perlMod.txt
```

contents of perl.txt are

```
a b
c
```

contents of perlMod.txt are

```
a
b
c
```

contents of perlMod.txt in hex are

```
61200D0A620D0A630D0A
```

Note that I have specified space as input record separator and "\n" as default output record separator. I am expecting two '0D0A's after b(62 in hex). One 0D0A is the new line after b. The other 0D0A belongs to output record separator. Why is there only one 0D0A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to think `<>` will still stop reading at a linefeed even though you changed the input record separator.

---

Your input contains `61 20 62 0D 0A 63` or `a␠b␍␊c`.

The first read reads `a␠`.

You print `a␠`.
To that, `$\` gets added, giving `a␠␊`.
Then `:crlf` does its translation, giving `a␠␍␊`.

**There is no other spaces in the file, so your second read reads the rest of the file: `b␍␊c`.**
Then `:crlf` does its translation, giving `b␊c`.

You print `b␊c`.
To that, `$\` gets added, giving `b␊c␊`.
Then `:crlf` does its translation, giving `b␍␊c␍␊`.

So, altogether, you get `a␠␍␊b␍␊c␍␊`, or `61 20 0D 0A 62 0D 0A 63 0D 0A`.

Comment: Yes. I thought <> will stop reading at new line though I have changed input record separator. This also means if I set $/ to space to read word by word, I will have to worry about this "a line ending word\nnext line first word" being counted as 'word'. Thanks for pointing this.